# Python BS4 remove all div ID's Classes, Styles etc

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, tags, beautifulsoup

i'm trying to parse html content from site with BS4. I got my html fragment, but i need to remove all tags classes, ID's, styles etc.

For example:

```
<div class="applinks">
<div class="appbuttons">
<a href="https://geo.itunes.apple.com/ru/app/cloud-hub-file-manager-document/id972238010?mt=8&amp;at=11l3Ss" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="Cloud Hub - File Manager, Document Reader, Clouds Browser and Download Manager">Загрузить</a>
<span onmouseout="jQuery('.wpappbox-8429dd98d1602dec9a9fc989204dbf7c .qrcode').hide();" onmouseover="jQuery('.wpappbox-8429dd98d1602dec9a9fc989204dbf7c .qrcode').show();">QR-Code</span>
</div>
</div>
```

i need to get:

```
<div>
<div>
<a href="https://geo.itunes.apple.com/ru/app/cloud-hub-file-manager-document/id972238010?mt=8&amp;at=11l3Ss" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="Cloud Hub - File Manager, Document Reader, Clouds Browser and Download Manager">Загрузить</a>
<span>QR-Code</span>
</div>
</div>
```

My code:

```
# coding: utf-8
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://lifehacker.ru/2016/08/29/app-store-29-august-2016/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
post_content = soup.find("div", {"class","post-content"})
print post_content
```

How i can to remove all tags attributes?

Answer (score 4):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://lifehacker.ru/2016/08/29/app-store-29-august-2016/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
for tag in soup():
    for attribute in ["class"]: # You can also add id,style,etc in the list
        del tag[attribute]
```

Comment: TypeError: 'Doctype' object does not support item deletion

Comment: I have tested with your url in my system..its working..I don't know why are you getting this error..you can also see the beautifulsoup documentation ..its the same way..@KonstantinRusanov

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

To remove all attributes from the tags in the scrapped data:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def CleanSoup(content):
    for tags in content.findAll(True): 
        tags.attrs = {}
    return content


url = "https://lifehacker.ru/2016/08/29/app-store-29-august-2016/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")
post_content = soup.find("div", {"class","post-content"})
post_content = CleanSoup(post_content)
```